# Save changes to tinymce inline editor in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm trying to save updates made in the inline tinymce editor in my rails app, but I don't know how to do it exactly as I want.  I want the inline editor to be able to save while the view is 'html_safe'.  I *can* save it fine if the form area is a text area (i.e. `<div class="editor"><%= form.text_area :content %></div>`), but I want to have the view in inline editor format so you can see your changes on the fly.

In the logs, it looks like the invitation params are closing before it's including the changes needed.  How do I do this so that the inline editor changes are saved correctly?

*Note: Everything else is working correctly, except the changes to the <%= @invitation.content %> are not being saved.*

View:

```
    <%= form_with(model: @invitation, local: true) do |form| %>

    <%= form.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event.id %>

    <div class="editor"><%= @invitation.content.html_safe %></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          tinyMCE.init({
            selector: '.editor',
            menubar: false,
            inline: true,
            plugins: "save",
            toolbar: "save"
          });
        </script>

<% end %>
```

And my output from the log is:

```
  Processing by InvitationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2ssewH/CSN7is0P2LVrMkEmwZXcgmQqjWTjgrE6gGqAEv4dmLXFjEuOFJ9TRia+JF59SB6kKu5Le1xvt/FoxPg==", "invitation"=>{"event_id"=>"29"}, "mce_0"=>"<h1>Second Test Event CHANGEHERE!</h1>\r\n<h2>09/02/18 @ 04:20</h2>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<hr />\r\n<p>Bring Cheese</p>", "commit"=>"Update Invitation", "id"=>"7"}
  Invitation Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:66
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:43
  Event Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 29], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:43
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:43
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events/29
```

And my controller is a basic object controller:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invitation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /invitations
  # GET /invitations.json
  def index
    @invitations = Invitation.all
  end

  # GET /invitations/1
  # GET /invitations/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /invitations/new
  def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
  end

  # GET /invitations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /invitations
  # POST /invitations.json
  def create
    @invitation = Invitation.new(invitation_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invitation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invitation, notice: 'Invitation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invitation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invitation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /invitations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invitations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invitation.update(invitation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invitation.event, notice: 'Invitation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invitation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @invitation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /invitations/1
  # DELETE /invitations/1.json
  def destroy
    @invitation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invitations_url, notice: 'Invitation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invitation
      @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invitation_params
      params.require(:invitation).permit(:name, :content, :event_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: 'I'm trying to save an inline tinymce editor in my rails app'  Im not sure what you mean by this. Do you mean you are trying to save data using a rich text editor? You want the content of the text_area to appear in a preview below the editor as html safe so you can preview what you have written in the editor on the fly?

Comment: Save the updates made to the `@invitation.content` done using the rich text editor (tinymce in this case).